# The method in the type is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

im trying to make a card game, but i'm having some small problems with it.  I am trying to add a Card currentCard from another classin my new list cards. and i get the error The method addLast(Card) in the type SingleLinkedList is not applicable for the arguments (DoubleLinkedList.Element).

```
public class CardList<E extends Comparable<? super E>> extends SingleLinkedList<E> {

private SingleLinkedList<Card> cards;

private int cardRow;                

public CardList(int cardRow) {

    this.cardRow = cardRow;
    cards = new SingleLinkedList<Card>();

        cards.addLast(CardDeck.currentCard);   // here is the error
    }
}
```

My addLast method in SingleLinkedList:

```
public class SingleLinkedList<E> {

protected transient Element<E> head;
protected transient int size;

public SingleLinkedList() {
    head = null;
    size = 0;
}

public void addLast(E value) {
    Element<E> temp = new Element<E>(value, null);
    if (head != null) {
        Element<E> finger = head;
        while(finger.next != null) {
            finger = finger.next;
        }
        finger.next = temp;
    } else {
        head = temp;
    }
    size++;
}
```

an the element class (inside the singlelinkedlist class)

```
protected static class Element<E> {

    public E value;
    public Element<E> next;

    public Element(E value, Element<E> next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

and the currentCard variable from the class DoubleLinkedList

```
 public class CardDeck<E extends Comparable<? super E>> extends DoubleLinkedList<E> {


private DoubleLinkedList<Card> cards;
static Element<Card> currentCard;
```

I know the problem is that i am trying to insert a element  into a method that expect to get a Card, but i just cant figure out how to convert it from generics to a specific type (card) or something.   I have been looking for some good tutorial about generics but haven't found something that helps me directly yet. So if someone either has some tips about solving my problem directly, or have a good link to a tutorial/description on the subject i would be very thankful!

If you need more info, or i need to rephrase something please tell me :)

Comment: I think it's pretty straight forward. Your `currentCard` is of type `Element<Card>`. According to the variable name I would expect it to be of type `Card` instead, if that was true then you would not see that error.

Comment: I remember when I was young and overused inheritance...

You should just use a built-in list for this kind of stuff and wrap it with your object, not inherit from your own custom List.

Comment: @Bhesh I was trying that as well, but then i get more problems with opreations like card.next etc, i suppose i would have to redo everything in the list without the E part or something. Was hoping there was an easier way to convert from Element<Card> to card or something

Comment: @josaphatv I wish i could just use the built in lists etc, but parts of the deal is we have to use our own implementation of lists, but all this generics stuff is giving me headaches :P

Comment: Is there any reason why you extend and delegate to the same list type?

Comment: @ArneBurmeister not sure what you mean by that, care to explain? :)

Comment: CardDeck extends DoubleLinkedList and also has a member of that type, CardList is similar. Why that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make `currentCard` variable of type `Card` instead of type `Element<Card>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the *Card* from the *Element* it comes in. `currentCard.value` should do what you want.

But perhaps you should save some headaches and just use a *java.util.List* instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you wrote your own LinkedList. Maybe it is homework?
As josaphatv suggested, using Java LinkedList will take your problem of implementing the LinkedList away.

And the main problem is just as josaphatv mentioned. You should pass in a Card, which is
currentCard.value instead of the Element itself. And you don't need to convert E to Card (though it is possible by using type casting (Card) value.

But, as I see, you don't call any specific method of Card nor having any TypeStrict operation on Card there. So really, there is no need to convert E to Card.

Now, in term of design and implementing, here are a lot of bad practice here, I will just note down 2 of the basic thing.

- In Element class, you violate Encapsulation with putting both your attribute public. This meaning saying any other Class can modify the atrribute to their heart content. In OOP, this is not recommended.
- As mentioned, why reinventing the wheel, using Java.util.List can do thing much better, try search LinkedList java on google.

Hope this helps